# Accessibility message in the iPhone SDK Console

Tags: iphone, console, accessibility, message

I just recently saw these lines in my app console output and wondered how they showed up. I don't think that I enabled any accessibility features. Can someone explain this to me please?

```
******* Accessibility Status Changed: On
********** Loading AX for: com.yourcompany.appname ************
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**They show up for everyone**. It's just showing that the Accessibility is enabled (VoiceOver, etc.). :)

Comment: Any idea why it might stop showing up? I seem to have lost mine, but only on iPod development

Comment: That would depend on the generation of device as well as the firmware version. I'm not exactly sure why it would stop showing up, but it's probably one of those two factors.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same warning. I changed the simulator to a different firmware version and it didn't appear, and switching back to the previous firmware the message appeared again.
Finally it disappeared after doing a device reset in the simulator.